# Need explanation on how this windows cmd batch script accomplishes the task of activating Microsoft Office 2016

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, office365, piracy

I do know that software piracy is a serious crime. Hence I am staying from that. But I came across a script which activates office 2016 using key Management Service(KMS) activation method.

But I am not completely sure how this script actually does that. Especially those lines involving >nul

**EDIT:** My doubts are what does those for loops and cscripts in the program do. As said by an user, if those are copied to a folder one up in the current directory, Why would it do that?

Does it kind of removing the files that are associated with license verification of the product?

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq5khDs9ofk

```
@echo off
title Activate Microsoft Office 2016 ALL versions for FREE!&cls&echo ============================================================================
&echo #Project: Activating Microsoft software products for FREE without software&echo ============================================================================
&echo.&echo #Supported products:&echo - Microsoft Office Standard 2016&echo - Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016&echo.&echo.

&(if exist "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office16\ospp.vbs" cd /d "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office16")
&(if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office16\ospp.vbs" cd /d "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office16")

&(for /f %%x in ('dir /b ..\root\Licenses16\proplusvl_kms*.xrm-ms') do cscript ospp.vbs /inslic:"..\root\Licenses16\%%x" >nul)
&(for /f %%x in ('dir /b ..\root\Licenses16\proplusvl_mak*.xrm-ms') do cscript ospp.vbs /inslic:"..\root\Licenses16\%%x" >nul)
&echo.&echo ============================================================================

&echo Activating your Office...&cscript //nologo ospp.vbs /unpkey:WFG99 >nul&cscript //nologo ospp.vbs /unpkey:DRTFM >nul
&cscript //nologo ospp.vbs /unpkey:BTDRB >nul
&cscript //nologo ospp.vbs /unpkey:CPQVG >nul
&cscript //nologo ospp.vbs /inpkey:XQNVK-8JYDB-WJ9W3-YJ8YR-WFG99 >nul&set i=1
:server
if %i%==1 set KMS_Sev=kms4.MSGuides.com
if %i%==2 set KMS_Sev=kms5.MSGuides.com
if %i%==3 set KMS_Sev=kms6.MSGuides.com
if %i%==4 goto notsupported
cscript //nologo ospp.vbs /sethst:%KMS_Sev% >nul
&echo ============================================================================&echo.&echo.
cscript //nologo ospp.vbs /act | find /i "successful" && (echo.&echo ============================================================================&echo.&echo 
#My official blog: MSGuides.com&echo.&echo
#How it works: bit.ly/kms-server&echo.&echo 
#Please feel free to contact me at msguides.com@gmail.com if you have any questions or concerns.&echo.&echo 
#Please consider supporting this project: donate.msguides.com&echo
 #Your support is helping me keep my servers running everyday!&echo.&echo ============================================================================
 &choice /n /c YN /m "Would you like to visit my blog [Y,N]?" & if errorlevel 2 exit) || (echo The connection to my KMS server failed! Trying to connect to another one... 
 & echo Please wait... & echo. & echo. & set /a i+=1 & goto server)
explorer "http://MSGuides.com"&goto halt
:notsupported
echo.&echo ============================================================================&echo Sorry! Your version is not supported.&echo Please try installing the latest version here: bit.ly/getmsps
:halt
pause
```

Comment: If this is inappropriate here, please do let me know. I shall remove it.

Comment: It is at least off topic here since it's not programming

Comment: `How it works: bit.ly/kms-server`

Comment: @CodyGray I am well aware of KMS way of activation. What does those for loops and cscript lines do?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are referring to these lines:

```
&(for /f %%x in ('dir /b ..\root\Licenses16\proplusvl_kms*.xrm-ms') do cscript ospp.vbs /inslic:"..\root\Licenses16\%%x" >nul)
&(for /f %%x in ('dir /b ..\root\Licenses16\proplusvl_mak*.xrm-ms') do cscript ospp.vbs /inslic:"..\root\Licenses16\%%x" >nul)
```

This being the case, here is what each part does:

```
for /f %%x in ('dir /b ..\root\Licenses16\proplusvl_kms*.xrm-ms')
```

Runs the `dir /b` command line tool (which will just list the file names) against the path `..\root\Licenses16\proplusvl_kms*.xrm-ms'` which is:

1. one folder up from the current directory
2. `root` folder within this folder
3. all file names matching the pattern `proplusvl_kms*.xrm-ms` within this folder

For each of these files, this command is run:

```
cscript ospp.vbs /inslic:"..\root\Licenses16\%%x" >nul
```

`cscript` is a Windows command which is used to execute Visual Basic Script files (vbs). In each iteration, `%%x` is replaced with the the respective value from the previous `dir` command results (which is a file name). So effective this runs the `ospp.vbs` passing in `..\root\Licenses16\[file name from 'dir']` as the parameter value for `/inslic` (which presumably the script understands).

The `>nul` simply redirects the output to nowhere instead of printing to the screen.